# Perl Sorting Array Numerically When Parts of Entry Contain Character

Tags: perl, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Perl, how can I sort an array using the value of a number inside each array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809804/using-perl-how-can-i-sort-an-array-using-the-value-of-a-number-inside-each-arra)

I have an array that looks like this:

```
my @arr = qw(r1.1  r10.1  r2.1   r33.1);
```

How can you sort them in Perl so that it yields:

```
  $VAR = ['r1.1',   'r2.1', 'r10.1',   'r33.1'];
```

Comment: `map "r$_", sort {$a <=> $b} map {substr $_, 1} @arr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sort subroutine that will work:

```
sub mySort {    
    $a =~ /^r(\d+).(\d+)$/;
    my ($a1, $a2) = ($1, $2);

    $b =~ /^r(\d+).(\d+)$/;
    my ($b1, $b2) = ($1, $2);

    return $a2 <=> $b2 if ($a1 == $b1);
    return $a1 <=> $b1;
}
```

To use it you do this:

```
my @sorted = sort mySort @arr;
```

Comment: This would correctly order, for example, qw(r1.2 r1.1) as well. I'm thinking of your elements like they are version numbers (the "r" made me think of 'revision') so therefore 1.10 would be different from (greater than) 1.1. If they're just real numbers this could be done more simply.

Comment: For a small dataset this is ok, but it's not a great solution - see the possible duplicate linked above.  The main problem is that for every comparison carried out in the sort, both `a` and `b` need to be regex'd - which could be many times for a long list.  The 'double return' is confusing, and not idiomatic at all: it's more normal to write something like `return $a1 <=> $b1 or $a2 <=> $b2;` In that case if `$a1 == $b1` then the first comparison has value zero, hence the next comparison is evaluated.

Comment: @martin clayton, `return $a1 <=> $b1 or $a2 <=> $b2;` means `(return $a1 <=> $b1) or ($a2 <=> $b2);`. Use `||` or parens.

Comment: @martin clayton, The double match is faster than using the Schwartzian Transform to eliminate the double match.

Comment: @sjs, `$a =~ /^r(\d+).(\d+)$/; my ($a1, $a2) = ($1, $2);` is a rather poor way or writing `my ($a1, $a2) = $a =~ /^r(\d+).(\d+)$/;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Sort::Key::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aKey%3a%3aNatural):

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);
my @arr = qw(r1.1  r10.1  r2.1   r33.1);
my @sorted = natsort @arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @sorted =
   sort {
      my @a = $a =~ /([0-9]+)/g;
      my @b = $b =~ /([0-9]+)/g;
      return $a[0] <=> $b[0] || $a[1] <=> $b[1];
   }
   @arr;
```

Probably faster:

```
my @sorted =
   map substr($_, 8),
   sort
   map pack('NNa*', /([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/, $_),
   @arr;
```