# Alphanumeric sort using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

```
@arr = qw(test1 test3 tes5 test2 test4 test8 test6 test7 test10 test9);
```

How can I sort this array and get the output like:

```
test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10
```

instead of

```
test1 test10 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8412078/223226

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do alpha numeric sort perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102518/how-to-do-alpha-numeric-sort-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom sort subroutine:

```
my @arr = qw(test1 test3 tes5 test2 test4 test8 test6 test7 test10 test9);

foreach ( sort { number_strip($a) <=> number_strip($b) } @arr ){
    say;
}

sub number_strip {
    $line = shift;
    my ($num) = $line =~ /(\d+)/;
    return $num;
}
```

---

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
tes5
test6
test7
test8
test9
test10
```

Comment: `.*?` is completely redundant.

Comment: You can also do it like this: `say for sort { $a =~ s/\D//gr <=> $b =~ s/\D//rg } @arr;`

Comment: @Sobrique Except that this will not work for all strings, e.g. `test5foo1` would erroneously become `51`.

Comment: This will do a strange thing with a string like `necrophilia5`. Doesn't the content of the values suggest that they are, well, *test* data?

Comment: Also a lot neater to `use List::UtilsBy qw( nsort_by );` so you can just call `nsort_by { number_strip($_) } @arr`

Answer (score 9):

### Why reinvent the wheel?

Just [`use Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Sort::Naturally 'nsort';

my @test = map 'test'.$_, reverse 1..10;
say for nsort @test;
```

prints

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9
test10
```

Comment: This would have been a better answer if it didn't include "Why invent the wheel?" and replaced the word "Just" with "You can"

Answer (score 1):

Split the string inside sort comparator and check one element after another. `$ta` stands for text from `a`, `$na` is the number and `$ra` is the rest of the string (if there is any):

```
@result = sort({
        my ( $ta, $na, $ra ) = $a =~ m/^(.*?)(\d+)(.*)$/;
        my ( $tb, $nb, $rb ) = $b =~ m/^(.*?)(\d+)(.*)$/;
        return $ta cmp $tb || $na <=> $nb || $ra cmp $rb;
    }
    @arr
);
```

Comment: Your postfix if-statements are not needed if you use the idiomatic way to apply sorting comparisons: `$ta cmp $tb || $na <=> $nb || $ra cmp $rb`

Answer (score 0):

```
my @sorted = map { s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/g; $_          } sort
             map { /(\d+)/sprintf("%06.6d",$1)/ge; $_ } @arr;
```

will sort your array naturally. Also I noticed the fact there's no *test5* element in your initial description, but *tes5* instead

to be explained this could be divided into parts. since Perl interpreter crawls expressions right to left first action is

```
my @sorted = map { s/(\d+)/sprintf("%06.6d",$1)/ge } @arr;
```

here we add zeroes between text and numbers to have 6 decimal places (this is a random number, may be any that satisfies current task)

then we sort the array lexically

```
@sorted = sort @sorted
```

an then remove inserted zeroes

```
@sorted = map { s/(^|\D)0+(\d)/$1$2/g } @sorted;
```

among main caveats - this will break elements like 'test04'

Comment: how will it shorten the notation?

Comment: Its not about making it shorter, its about using the right tools.

Comment: but why `map` is *righter* than `grep`? in't `grep` a part of Perl core?  where is the abuse of `grep`?

Comment: You can use a shovel to hammer in a nail, that does not mean that using a shovel is the right way to do it. `grep` is made to remove items from a list, or to verify some quality. You are using it to alter values, and you are explicitly adding a `1` to not make it filter out items.

Comment: The first part will remove zeroes regardless of whether you added them or not. You might consider using a Schwartzian transform instead.

Comment: Since this is a learning environment, teaching people the wrong thing, and not explaining what you are doing, is a bad thing to do. As such, if you do not update your answer, I will feel obligated to downvote it.

Comment: this will never work as it is after you edited my answer

Comment: It was either that or downvote you, and I opted to do this. You're right, it doesn't work, because `map` needs a return value, so you need to add `; $_`. That's a pitfall of correcting someone else's flawed logic. If you want, I can rollback the changes and downvote instead.

Comment: Well, if we talk about learning process, downvote me and post more righteous variant would be more consistent than making edits with such 'pitfalls', because we're not the only participants of this thread, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer to avoid the module then you can write a sort block that splits each string into an alpha part and a numeric part and compares them separately.

But this relies on the format always being `AAA999` and I'd prefer [`Sort::Naturally`](https://p3rl.org/Sort::Naturally) anyway in case the format changes in the future

Note that your sample data has a spurious `tes5`, which I assume was a typo but still qualifies as test data. It is sorted before all the other values because `tes` sorts before `test` lexically

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @arr = qw(test1 test3 tes5 test2 test4 test8 test6 test7 test10 test9 );

say for sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map [ /([a-z]+)(\d+)/i ], $a, $b;
    $aa->[0] cmp $bb->[0] or $aa->[1] <=> $bb->[1];
} @arr;
```

#### output

```
tes5
test1
test2
test3
test4
test6
test7
test8
test9
test10
```