# mapping and sorting array of files in perl

Tags: perl, dictionary, sorting

I have this array of files which looks like this :

```
my @html_pages_files = ("html.17", "html.9", "html.0", "html.10");
```

I will put the extension of the file after the sort part. Basically the file name will be /html.\d/. The thing is I'm trying to sort it using map and sort function :

```
map { $_->[1] }
  sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
     map { /html\.(.*)/; [$1, $_] }
        @html_pages_files;
print "@html_pages_files\n";
```

However the output remains the same as the original array. I've followed step by step @Chas. Owens answer here : [Using Perl, how can I sort an array using the value of a number inside each array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809804/using-perl-how-can-i-sort-an-array-using-the-value-of-a-number-inside-each-arra). Note that I'm pretty new to perl so I don't get all the details.

Does anybody seed where the error is ?
Thank you!!!

Comment: For one, you're not checking to see if the regex match inside that map block succeeds.  Right now if it doesn't match for some reason, you'll never know it and `$1` will have the value from the previous regex match.  I'd change it to `/.../ or die` if you expect that it will always pass.

Answer (score 6):

You never save the sorted results!

```
@html_pages_files =
   map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
     map { /html\.(.*)/; [$_, $1] }
      @html_pages_files;
```

(For consistency, I always put the whole string in the first element of the array.)

Answer (score 4):

Your sorting logic looks correct but you are not assigning the result of the operation to anything, so you are not changing `@html_pages_files`. Try

```
@html_pages_files = map {$_->[1] } 
                    sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} 
                    map {/html\.(.*)/; [$1, $_]} @html_pages_files;
```

Comment: I've got it. actually you have to create a knew array in order to work, it looks like this :



    my @sorted = map{$_->[1]} sort{$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} map{/html\.(.*)/; [$1, $_]} @html_pages_files;

Nevertheless thank you for your advices!!!

Comment: @user2007958, You can, but you don't have, as both of us have shown.